# Fire AJAX for certain selectItem in selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have following selectOneMenu

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}">
    <f:selectItem value="#{bean.item1}"/>
    <f:selectItem value="#{bean.item2}"/>
    <f:selectItem value="#{bean.item3}"/>

    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.item3AjaxEvent}" update="fieldToUpdate"></p:ajax>

</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Now I want to do some AJAX action only when `item3` is selected from selectOneMenu. Not for all the items. Is there any way of doing that?

Putting ajax tag will fire the event for all the select items. I don't want to generate unwanted ajax requests to server.

Comment: describe your AJAX action ? What does it mean ?

Comment: @Makky I have edited code in my question. Please have another look.

Comment: `p:ajax` has a `onstart` attribute. Check your condition and try returning false from that function to stop execution.

Comment: @djaqeel simply in your item3AjaxEvent method check for selecgted value . if it is item3 then do your business login otherwise just return.

Comment: @mabi returning false would not stop the ajax request. it's called onstart, it means it's already started

Comment: @HatemAlimam I'll defer to optimus.prime [saying](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17014#p51899): "Try returning false on start."

Comment: Have you tried it ?.. I have just tried it and it didn't work, ajax request fired anyway ! @mabi

Comment: @HatemAlimam lacking a primefaces environment here. I'll have to take the word of [many](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1792) [users](http://wrschneider.blogspot.de/2012/01/primefaces-ajax-callbacks-onstart-vs.html) [around the internet](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/primefaces-ajax-callbacks/). YMMV.

Comment: @mabi well it seems legit, and I remember now that I have used this before in an ajax inside a command button and it worked ... well maybe this time didn't work for some reason in my environment... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in this way.

***xhtml***

```
 <p:selectOneMenu widgetVar="selectOneMenuWV"
                  onchange="checkItem()">  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />                             
 </p:selectOneMenu> 


<p:remoteCommand name="myRemoteCommand" 
             actionListener="#{bean.item3AjaxEvent()}"  
             update="fieldToUpdate"/>

<script>
    function checkItem() {
       if(selectOneMenuWV.getSelectedValue() == 3) {
            myRemoteCommand();
       }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.